# How to offer anitleeching method of a JAD OTA link

Tags: php, mysql, jad, ota

Ok, I am currently using a download script in PHP which queries a mySQL database and checks if that token has been downloaded (this token I create manually through a generate script). So for example my generate link would be http://www.mysite.com/ota/download.php?id=6gs78sj39h3e

I have the proper headers to allow for a correct OTA download and the script functions properly...however this is my concern....If a user does not use his/her mobile device to download the JAD file and instead use's a browser the browser presents a save as dialogue. If the user downloads the file offered it is named as download.php and the contents are of the JAD file. Within this jad file are links to the .cod files.

For example if my generated link was http://www.mysite.com/ota/download.php?id=6gs78sj39h3e
If they opened this jad file in a text editor anyone with 2 cents will know that "MYAPP-1.cod"
resides within the /ota/ directory and then can proceed to download all of the *.cod files and have the opportunity to offer this download elsewhere...

What is the best approach to prevent this? I was thinking possibly checking to see if they are using a blackberry browser and if not deny the link and if they are proceed to download but I am pretty sure you can 'fake' the browser identification if you really wanted....So any suggestions on how to better accomplish offering a JAD download without allowing the users to view the contents of the JAD file?

Comment: If you don't want something to be downloadable, then don't put it into a publicly accessible directory on your website.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of saying it you don't really have any options: you should do the user-agent check for the Blackberry browser because for the more casual user who is not used to playing with browser user agents that will work, but for anyone who is dedicated they'll be able to get around it.

What is probably most useful is to automatically expire the links after a certain time: generate a link to not only the JAD file but to the COD files as well and then make those links expire after a day or two. Will at least reduce the chance that the links get redistributed or that they know specifically where the COD files are. Not sure how that will work with the Blackberry installer though.